# Efficient downloading of 10-K filings from SEC website

Tags: perl, edgar

I use the following perl code to mass download 10-Ks from the SEC website.  However, I get an "Out of memory!" message every few hundred files when the script apparently gets stuck processing an especially large 10-K filing.  Any ideas how I can avoid this "Out of memory!" error for large files?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

open LOG , ">download_log.txt" or die $!;
######## make sure the file with the ids/urls is in the 
######## same folder as the perl script
open DLIST, "downloadlist.txt" or die $!;
my @file = <DLIST>;

foreach my $line (@file) {
        #next if 0.999 > rand ;
        #print "Now processing file: $line\n" ;
    my ($nr, $get_file) = split /,/, $line;
    chomp $get_file;
    $get_file = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/" . $get_file;
    if ($get_file =~ m/([0-9|-]+).txt/ ) {
        my $filename = $nr . ".txt";
        open OUT, ">$filename" or die $!;
        print "file $nr \n";
        my $response =$ua->get($get_file);
        if ($response->is_success) {
            print OUT $response->content;
            close OUT;
        } else {
            print LOG "Error in $filename - $nr \n" ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Sinan Ünür.  I am unfamiliar with how response_data handlers keep my files from being stored in memory (and with response_data handlers more generally).  Could you provide a little insight into how you would most efficiently incorporate that into the code above?

Comment: Actually, let `$ua` [handle the saving](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#get).

Comment: Is that different from the "my $response = $ua->($get_file);" line currently in the code?  What exactly are you suggesting?

Comment: I am suggesting you do not read the entire file content into a variable. Do read what I linked to: ***If a $filename is provided with the :content_file option, then the response content will be saved here instead of in the response object.***

Comment: Not related to the out of memory, and irrelevant if you follow Sinan's good advice, but you almost always want to use ->decoded_content, not ->content

Comment: I've added the :content_file option, and so far I've not had any problems with running out of memory.  I won't know for sure until it's done processing in a couple of days, if problems arise I will repost.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar problem using threads and thousands of LWP requests. Never figured out what the memory leak was, but switching to HTTP::Tiny resolved it.

Going from [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) to [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) is simple:

```
use HTTP::Tiny;

my $ua = HTTP::Tiny->new;

my $response =$ua->get($get_file);
if ($response->{success}) {
    print OUT $response->{content};
```

... of course `HTTP::Tiny` could just do the saving part for you, like `LWP`.

You could also try to make a new `LWP` object inside the loop, hoping for the garbage collection to kick in, but it didn't work for me either. There is something inside the `LWP` monster that leaks.

Edit: There could also be a problem with trying to download a 2gb file into a string, the [mirror](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny#mirror) method should solve that for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Very good first answer. :-)

Comment: *"There is something inside the LWP monster that leaks"* The problem is not in the LWP module suite, which has been extensively used and tested by a huge number of people since it was first released in May 1996. If you have written a program that uses LWP and leaks memory then it is not a problem with the module.

Answer (score 1):

Just get `LWP` to store the response data directly into a file instead of in the `HTTP::Response` object. It's also simpler to code that way

Here's an example program. I can't test it at present but it does compile

I've recently noticed a lot of people writing code to read entire files into memory before processing the data and I don't understand why it's so popular. It's wasteful of memory and is often more difficult to code a solution that way. I've changed your program to read a line at a time of the download list file and use it directly instead of storing it into an array

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

open my $dl_fh,  '<', 'downloadlist.txt' or die "Can't open download list file: $!";

open my $log_fh, '>', 'download_log.txt' or die "Can't open log file: $!";

STDOUT->autoflush;

while ( <$dl_fh> ) {

    # next if 0.999 > rand;
    # print "Now fetching file: $_";

    chomp;
    my ($num, $dl_file) = split /,/;

    unless ( $dl_file =~ /[0-9|-]+\.txt/ ) {
        print $log_fh qq{Skipping invalid file "$dl_file"\n};
        next;
    }

    my $url      = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/$dl_file";
    my $filename = "$num.txt";

    print qq{Fetching file $filename\n};

    my $resp = $ua->get($url, ':content_file' => $filename);

    printf $log_fh qq{Download of "%s" %s\n},
            $filename,
            $resp->is_success ?
            'successful' :
            'FAILED: ' . $resp->status_line;
}
```

Comment: I have verified that this code does the job as well.  The processing speed appears to be relatively similar between both sets of code.

Comment: @Rick: Thanks. I appear to have been hit by the drive-by downvoter! The other answer has the disadvantage that it still reads the whole file into memory before writing it to disk, which unnecessarily wastes memory. I'm surprised that `HTTP::Tiny` performs any differently from `LWP` to be honest, as the core problem of memory space hasn't been fixed. This code writes data straight to disk as the data arrives from the internet.